# SafeCracker File: min-width/min-height for Images

Tags: safecracker, settings, file-uploads

Is there a way to set a «min-width» for images to a «SafeCracker File»-Field (type: Images)?

We have a SafeCracker-Form, where Users are allowed to upload Images — but these should have a min-size of 512x512 Pixels.

There are Settings for max-width/-height in edit_upload_preferences, but I haven't found settings for min-width/-height so far.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately the EE file upload library has no extension hooks you can use to add extra routines to the process of uploading files from outside the File Manager.

However, you could use SafeCracker's `safecracker_submit_entry_start` hook ([docs](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/safecracker/development.html#safecracker-submit-entry-start)) to inspect your upload (which will likely be in the `$_FILES` global variable), run `getimagesize()` on it ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)), and then if it doesn't meet your minimum requirements, return an error:

```
return $this->EE->output->show_user_error('submission', 'Your image does not meet the minimum size requirements.');
```

That should get you started.